# Chrome 71 - Flash & Cookies

Tags: google-chrome, actionscript-3, flash, cookies

After Chrome 71 update came out Chrome doesn't send anymore cookies made by Flash client when creating POST request but it does store cookies that are send on response. This has been working just fine before and was just broken by the Chrome update. On all other browsers this still works just fine.

The Flash client is located on https://pr3hub.com and on login it creates POST request to the API server https://api.pr3hub.com which returns cookie that is used in following requests to authenticate the user actions. Chrome does store this cookie but will not send it on any other requests.

The login request is done using the following:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.loginCallback);

var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVariables.username = this.m.loginPanel.userNameField.textBox.text;
urlVariables.password = this.m.loginPanel.passwordField.textBox.text;

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(Settings.getAPIDomain() + "/login");
urlRequest.data = urlVariables;
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

If you are curious about the back-end code its publicly available on GitHub: https://github.com/isokissa3/Platform-Racing-3-Backend

**UPDATE:** Looks like Chrome has changed how SameSite is handled in cookies thus breaking the site. I have changed it from "Lax" to "None" for now. Hopefully there is better option.

Comment: Yes, Chrome 71 did change how they handle SameSite cookies, but I haven't found any information about how or why.

Comment: @ChristianDavén Hmm, interesting. I was too unable to find anything thus the confusion. Hopefully it will be addressed how and why, I would assume this would break quite few sites in production.